# Range of the radial coordinate for the Poincare-AdS$_3$ geometry

Tags: anti-de-sitter-spacetime

The metric of the Poincare-AdS$_3$ geometry is given in the Wikipedia article on the [Poincare coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space#Poincar.C3.A9_coordinates) of AdS$_3$ geometry:

$$ds^{2} = \alpha^{2}\left(\frac{du^{2}}{u^{2}} + u^{2}g_{\alpha\beta}dx^{\alpha}dx^{\beta}\right),$$

where $\alpha$ is supposedly the AdS$_3$ radius.

---

It appears that $0 < r < \infty$, in which the Poincare-AdS$_3$ geometry is not a cylinder.

But isn't the Poincare-AdS$_3$ geometry a cylinder? Where have I gone wrong in my thinking?

Comment: According to the Wiki-page you linked, "...where 
$\alpha$  is a nonzero constant with dimensions of length (the radius of curvature)" and "Topologically, anti-de Sitter is $S^1 \times \mathbb R^{n−1}$". (under the section *Definition and Properties*)

Comment: So, this geometry indeed has $r$ ranging from 0 to $\infty$?

Comment: I'd say so, but I'm no expert...